# Sitecore config patch update sharedSessionState to mongo

Tags: sitecore, session-state, patch, sitecore8

Trying to apply the configuration patch to update the shared session state to use mongo per doco below:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/session_state/walkthrough_configuring_a_shared_session_state_database_using_the_mongodb_provider

However bit stuck with best way to patch it.  One option is to delete the **sharedSessionState** node and add the mongo settings.

Any help will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove existing `<sharedSessionState>` node. Just use the patch below:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState>
        <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">mongo</patch:attribute>
        <providers>
             <add
                 name="mongo"
                 type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider,
                 Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB"
                 connectionStringName="session"
                 pollingInterval="2"
                 compression="true"
                 sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Just remember to add it **after** `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` file.

Comment: Thanks Marek. Is it ok to set this Mongo sharedsessionstate for both CMS and CD? Or should be only applied to CD?

Comment: I'm not sure but it should be ok to use mongo on CM server as well. I don't see any reason why would it break anything.